# Check shared Post on Facebook Successfully or discarded

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

Facebook SDK always call onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) after discarding the post.
I am using the share post of the Facebook SDK, but always call onSuccess listener even after the discard or cancel the post.
I am using this facebook SDK for share the post `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[4,5)'`and use this doc.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android/

```
shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                Log.e(TAG, result.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "shared succrssfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "shared cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "shared error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

and have onActivity Result is

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

but always called onSuccess listner , how can I find the post has been succesfully post.

have checked with multiple link but not got any solution yet so please help me out.

## [Post Id facebook share dialog always return null in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470850/post-id-facebook-share-dialog-always-return-null-in-android)

### [FB share dialog cancel callback not working in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019115/fb-share-dialog-cancel-callback-not-working-in-android)

Comment: Why would you need to know? You are not allowed to “reward” users for sharing in any way, hope you are aware of that. (Might also be that Facebook has deliberately disabled that by now, _because_ to many devs abused it for such non-allowed stuff.)

Comment: @misorude thanks for reply can you provide me the link for not allow for a reward after sharing the post.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse, 4.5, and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5

Comment: hello @Amit Verma try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776896/check-if-facebook-post-was-successful-from-android-application   may it will help you.

Comment: @misorude thanks a lot for the help, can we achieve this in downgrade the SDK , is it possible

Comment: "not allowed" means that it does not matter if it works with a downgraded api (or sdk, or whatever). facebook removed the possibility to get a callback for a good reason.

Comment: @luschn okay thanks for giving the answer, you saved my day

Comment: why downgrade , I dint find any solution yet so I post , and now got to know the policy of facebook which is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we can not recognize the post has been successful or not because the policy has been given by Facebook.

**Don't incentivize people to post content on Facebook or give the impression that posting to Facebook will be rewarded. For example, don’t give people anything in exchange for them posting to Facebook (i.e. don’t give or promise virtual goods, achievements, coupons, discounts, access to content or extra entries in a promotion, if they post content to Facebook).**

the policy of Facebook has been given below.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5

https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse